# Woocommerce - Change Add to Cart Button text depending on some conditions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need help from an experienced programmer from here... I have a site that sells Montessori PDF's, Courses, a blog, and more - made from scratch by me. Can be checked at: https://insideoutmontessori.ro/

My issue is Add to Cart Button - I want to show different text depends on conditions - and is not :) Let me explain...

I use a snippet to modify Add to cart Button Text (CUMPARA - means Buy in english) - this is already done by the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' ); 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text' );

// To change add to cart text on single product page
function woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text() {
    if ( ! is_admin()) {
        return __( 'Cumpără', 'woocommerce' ); 
    }
}

// To change add to cart text on product archives(Collection) page
function woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text() {
    if ( ! is_admin()) {
        return __( 'Cumpără', 'woocommerce' ); 
    }
}
```

I use to put a product without price, to announce next PDF - is like a teaser. Now is not active because o don't work for the moment to something new. For this i manage to alter price to be "In lucru" - means Work in progress in English - but i do not manage to change the button text from CUMPARA to VEZI DETALII (means MORE DETAILS in English). This product is not purchasable and I don't manage to use this condition to change the button text...

Also - for products already added to cart i want to change the Add to cart Button text to ADAUGAT IN COS - means Added to Cart in English - for the moment when the user came back to all products page and browse thru them. I manage before to do this (code below works but...) but i receive some errors (Critical ones) and after change the code i receive only something with JSON message in a red box, in Editor, when i try to save a page witch contains woocommerce shortcodes... I deactivate this snippet to lose the error.

The code is below:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'wc_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'wc_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );

function wc_product_add_to_cart_text( $text, $product ){

    if ( ! is_admin()) {
        $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->get_id() );
        $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );

        if ( $in_cart ) {
            $text = "Adăugat în coș";
        }
        
        return $text;
    }
}
```

So - the bottom line is that I need a snippet that changes the Add to Cart Button text depending on these three conditions, simultaneously:

- if the product is in the cart - the button will show: Adaugat in cos (Already in the cart)
- if the product is without a price - the button will show: Vezi detalii (See more details)
- otherwise - button will show: Cumpara (Buy)

I think this is the correct approach - i mean this needs to be done with one function that alters button text depends on that three conditions.

Thanks!